# SQL query for determining unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to display corresponding dates for serial number, sometimes the query doesn't display values as the `Partobj` column doesn't have unique values.

How could I get serial number which have unique `Partobj`?

```
select 
    ib.Date1,w.Date2,w.Date3
from 
    table1 w 
left outer join 
    table2 ib on w.Partobj=ib.Partobj
where 
    ib.SerialNumber = '12we'
```

Comment: Do you mean you only want those with a record in ib2.

Comment: yes, if i can get unique serial number

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any sample data you could do something similar to this, where you join on `table2` looking for only the `DISTINCT` records:

```
select ib.Date1,w.Date2,w.Date3
from table1 w 
left outer join 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Date1, Partobj, SerialNumber
    FROM table2 
) ib
on w.Partobj=ib.Partobj
where ib.SerialNumber = '12we'
```

If you post some sample data from both tables, it would be helpful.